# Can I register a function that calls a specific template function based on a string defining its type?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, metadata

I wrote a little editor for Qt.  It takes in a pointer, and based on the type of attribute (determined by a string), it will pull data from it using a templated function.

*(For example, if the type is "point", it will call `getBoundValue<QPoint3>` on the pointer.)*

This works fine in practice.  But I'm setting it up as a library so others can use it and I assume they'll want to add support for other types.  The problem is I don't want them to have to modify the original source code, but either inherit from the class or register callbacks for new types. I don't know how I'd implement the latter option since I couldn't pass a string type and class type together, could I?

If I want to allow users to add support for their own types, would they have to implement a subclass of my attribute editor that handles these values?  Or is there a way I could reorganize my code so users can maybe pass in the functionality to handle the new type like "rectangle", and a type Rectangle that's calls `getBoundValue<Rectangle>()`?

Here's some example code, where I see if the object is of a certain type.  If so, I call the matching template function on it:

```
AttributeEditor::update(Bindable* instance) {
    _instance = instance;
    clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < _instance->attributeCount(); i++) {
        Attribute attr = _instance->at(i);

        QList<QStandardItem*> attributeRow;
        QStandardItem* nameItem = new QStandardItem(
            attribute->property("name").toString()
        );

        attributeRow << nameItem;

        QList< QList<QStandardItem*> > subRows;

        if (attr->property("getter").isValid()) {

            std::cout << attr->type().toStdString() << std::endl;

            QString value = "?";
            if (attr->type() == "point3" || attr->type() == "vector3") {
                QVector3D p = getBoundValue<QVector3D>(_instance, attr);

                /* ... */
            }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Something to bear in mind is that templates are a *compile-time phenomenon*.  If you find yourself trying to do things with templates at runtime...I'll suggest you're probably using the wrong tool.  In any case...for completeness, could you provide your definition for `Attribute`, and perhaps a bit more context for what you are really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code will not know external classes, templates or otherwise, you will need to expose a registration mechanism that accepts the following:

1. Name of type (string). e.g. "rectangle"
2. Interface

The interface should have a pure virtual method called `getBoundValue`. All classes that want the functionality should implement the interface.

Example:

```
struct IShape {
   virtual QVector3D getBoundValue() = 0;
   // more shape methods
   ...
};

class Rectangle {
   QVector3D getBoundValue();
};

// register interface prototype - exported from your library
void RegisterShape( IShape* pShape, const QString& name );
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, but used a "handler" class since each attribute type will need to implement a set of functions and users won't have to register each one separately.

Comment: That's how it's done, the interface holds all the methods, so you just register the interface.